# Assaje or assai?

Tags: difference, regional

I'm not an Italian speaker, and I wanted to know which is the difference of assaje and assai, for example on the song Caruso the correct lyrics is "ti voglio bene assaje", or "te voglio bene assai"?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in these Neapolitan-Italian vocabularies, [*assaie*](http://www.vesuvioweb.com/it/wp-content/uploads/Giuseppe-Giacco-Vocabolario-napoletano-vesuvioweb.pdf) or [*assaje*](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/57205925/A._LLN-2018-WEB-libre.pdf?1534518833=&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B+filename%3DA_Lessico_e_Letteratura_del_Dialetto_Na.pdf&Expires=1706105755&Signature=csnLYK74t5BRdaEkithdpM%7E2UhvT59pwwnmbWMn7VbxSbTZuxdHlXqys00MbB7jSD7tGDpKp0-s4qQ%7EvAzZ60zap0RJAZLGGbfpGdlqYC2YUBF3-JvMoN5GkB3eli6UncFX4QPUe0wUWxAkjygNGYdMQPv4BsK2vc0nFs4xAVJ0deFRcjWwI-8Bi5ucnao37UPklaku%7EcTkM-gF3HztHEdiV4byqMz-UciBwCVCoiPPwHMiGZtGUR5paYU34LLxThi5ZLhwrWibGQyJWrbrFoQyShBE1RdRPUznnVuk3DRUH9ZlQBE7J1uemgUZafHALm0szd-4iiZWZWApCFSI4-w__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA) is a Neapolitan word, whereas *assai* is an Italian one. An example of usage in literature that comes from the second link is

> Chiù assaje ’e ll’at’anno s’arrepecchia ’a fronna (from a poem by Achille Serrao).

Answer (score 2):

Assaje is an alternative form of the Neapolitan adverb Assai.
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assaje

Assai is a Neapolitan as well as a Sicilian adverb.
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assai#Neapolitan

Caruso also sings in Neapolitan (nnapulitana)

Comment: Credo che sia giusta questa precisazione che fa esponapule, perché anche *assai* credo che sia una parola non solo italiana, ma napoletana.
Sono cose davvero difficili da stabilire una volta per tutte perché può cambiare da vocabolario a vocabolario, e da testo a testo di lingua napoletana. 

Però vedo usi autorevoli di *assai* in napoletano, ad esempio:

 *Me pare a me ch'a fa sta babelonia Nce vo assai manco ch'a tirà na sciaveca*
https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Vocabolario_del_dialetto_napolitano_(Rocco_1882)/B

Comment: Il dizionario Rocco è un dizionario storico, su cui ho visto persino tesi di dottorato.

Io, essendo di Napoli, avrei detto che *assai*  è napoletano, perché in certo casi l’uso di *assaje* non l'ho mai sentito e mi suona strano, es. davanti a un aggettivo come *bello*: *assai bello*, mi sembra naturale, *assaje bello* non l’ho mai sentito e mi sembra cacofonico.

Comment: Romano qui, ma formulo un'ipotesi: forse dipende dalla posizione (prima o dopo la parola a cui si riferisce, per esempio)?

Comment: Secondo me è un fatto eufonico, in cui c'entra anche la posizione. Davanti a *bello*, *assaie*  è cacofonico, difficile da pronunciare, davanti a una vocale, mi viene in mente *assaie impurtante*, mi suona bene. Oppure guarda il bel verso citato da Charo nella sua risposta,  lì c'è una *e* dopo. Ci dovrei ripensare meglio, non ci ho mai pensato, ma mi pare così.

Comment: Comunque dubito che ci siano regole fisse.